# How to recreate jenkins credentials.xml?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have accidentally deleted credentials.xml file in jenkins_home. How do I recreate it? Because I still can see and access the values in the gui

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to decrypt and dump the creds: https://github.com/hoto/jenkins-credentials-decryptor

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.